# How to replicate the back button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, back-button, textcolor

I understand that the only way to change the color of the text of the back button is to make your own custom button:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = yourCustomBackButton;
```

My question is: How do I create a back button that takes tint color into account and looks exactly the same as the default back button except for the color of the text (unless it's white)?

Answer (score 2):

Add a category to the UINavigationBar and set it's background color there.  This code also shows how to use an image.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

/***
 // use a custom color
 UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:.455 green:.365 blue:0 alpha:.9];
 3    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 4    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
 5    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
 6    self.tintColor = color;
 ***/

// use a custom background image
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: [PlistVariables sharedInstance].navbarBackgroundImageName ];
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
self.tintColor = [PlistVariables sharedInstance].navbarTintColor;
 }
```

Here's some sample output using RGB 192,93,0 for background brown:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but you haven't changed the color of the text in the back button. You don't even mention the back button in the answer. You don't mention any button in the answer. Are you sure it's my question you're answering? Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the effort, but I don't see what this has to do with my question.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea came from a fellow named Brandon Jones. I wish I were clever enough to think of these things myself.  Sigh.

Comment: I guess Mike thought you wanted to use an image as background for the navigation bar, so you could still use an original bar button with tint. Using his solution you can set an image for the navigation bar while using any tint you want for the back button.

Comment: @Erik - maybe I misunderstood - you can set the tint color of the background, and the text color is already white, and it looks exactly like the default back button (because it is one).  What color do you want the text? You question implied white - i.e. no change.

Comment: Does this help "change the color of the text of the back button"? Otherwise this answer should probably be migrated to another question. It seems to elegantly solve something, but not my problem.

Comment: @Mike Aha, so that's the misunderstanding. I want it to be any color and if the color is white I want it to look exactly like the default button pixel for pixel.

Comment: @Mike I updated the question so that it will (hopefully) be harder to misunderstand. Do you think that's enough or is it still unclear what I'm asking for?

Comment: @Erik - my apologies.  Yes your question is clear.  Unfortunately, I don't see any way to get access to the color of that text in the built-in back button.  So if you create your own, you'd have to have a UIView with a base image of the right shape, superimpose a UILabel on top of it (so you can control the text color), and then either put a transparent button on top of that or handle the UIView gestures yourself.  Good luck.  Sorry for the detour.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not possible to change the text color of the back button. You can however assign a custom view to the leftBarButtonItem property. I've put together a simple little project showing how to do that that recreates the in/out animation of the standard iOS UI. Takes a bit of hacking, but you should be able to assign a button with a label in it to the custom view and update that.

https://github.com/typeoneerror/BBCustomBackButtonViewController